# How to format xpath values as map?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am using the Xpath Notebook extension for VSCode. I am trying to extract information and get them, ideally as a table. So my goal is to map the selected data to a map like this:

```
Array<{
  name: string,
  text: string
}>
```

The input xml looks like this:

```
<Values>
    <Value name="TestValue">
        <Text text="Test text"/>
    </Value>
    <Value name="Another">
        <Text text="Another test"/>
    </Value>
</Values>
```

My code snippet looks like this:

```
doc("C:\..pathto..\test.xml")//Value/[@name!string(),./Text/@text!string()]
```

The output looks like this:

```
[
    [
        "TestValue",
        "Test text"
    ],
    [
        "Another",
        "Another test"
    ]
]
```

So I get all the data I need, but in the format I need it.
Is there any simple way to map it to the format I have shown above?

I already tried some testing with map:entry, but so far I have not had any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for an XPath 3.1 map is e.g. `map { 'name' : string(@name), 'text' : string(Text/@text) }` so in the context of your sample I guess you want an array of maps with e.g.

```
doc("C:\..pathto..\test.xml")/Values ! array { Value ! map { 'name' : string(@name), 'text' : string(Text/@text) } }
```